# Pull Products To BigCommerce Home Page

Tags: bigcommerce, templating

We're not trying to host our whole site on B.C. We only wanted to use B.C. to host our products and checkout process. Is there a way to pull all products to the home page? Ideally we want the content on '/categories/' to be displayed on the home page. If not possible we would like to restrict access to the home page and set up a redirect to go to '/categories/'. Is this possible?

Need to figure out how to do this in their templating system.

Redirect is worst-case scenario

Comment: Can you specify if you are using the blueprint theming engine or stencil?

Comment: I guess the theme is called 'Classic Next (light)'